# Ignite could not consumption the WAL log and release the OS buffer when persisten on

Tags: java, ignite

Ignite could not consumption the WAL log and release the OS buffer when persisten on

I have one ignite server with 128G memory, and with persistent enabled to keep my data safe.

As I got from the official document, my understanding:
When Persitent enabled, Ignite will first save data changes to OS buffer(I check this 
as buff/cache in linux command free -mh), 
and then write to WAL log, and via checkpoint process periodically to analyze the WAL
log and free the parsed WAL log disk space and release the used OS buffer, correct me if I am wrong.

But in my testing, When Ignite start to handling traffic, I found the OS buffer increase quickly
and check the WAL log directory, there are lots wal log generated in order,
 nearly same as the size with buff/cache.

```
[root@Redis1 apache-ignite]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        109G        995M        1.7G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
      127G
```

Only a few minutes, the free column reduced quickly vs. buff/cache increasing

```
[root@Redis1 apache-ignite]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         15G         85G        995M         25G        108G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
```

and the WAL log size and segement numbers keep increasing also, still nearly same as the size with buff/cache.

I have check the ignite log, the checkpoint process audit each 3minutes:

```
[05:30:05,818][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#107][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint started [checkpointId=9428aebc-f2b0-4d33-bed6-fb9a1ad49848, startPtr=FileWALPointer [idx=341, fileOff=50223036, len=420491], checkpointLockWait=0ms, checkpointLockHoldTime=860ms, walCpRecordFsyncDuration=245ms, pages=89627, reason='timeout']
[05:30:22,429][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#107][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint finished [cpId=9428aebc-f2b0-4d33-bed6-fb9a1ad49848, pages=89627, markPos=FileWALPointer [idx=341, fileOff=50223036, len=420491], walSegmentsCleared=0, markDuration=1288ms, pagesWrite=844ms, fsync=15767ms, total=17899ms]
```

But for the output of "free -mh" command,  "free" column could not be released, still increasing with traffic going on, even when I stopped traffic, it also
doesn't get reduced,  If i keep send traffic, the available memory keep reducing, and finally the avail memory reduced to around hundread MegaBytes,

```
[root@Redis1 apache-ignite]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         16G        370M        971M        108G        107G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
```

When this happens(free memory exhausting?), all my service based on ignite stop to handle my new request anymore, for ignite, it hangs.

I also notice the Checkpoint log with reason='timeout', i don't know if this stand for that ignite could not properly parse the WAL log and free OS cache buffer?
Is there anyway to let checkpoint work normally to free the memroy?

My question is how could I do something to prevent ignite exhausting the available memory, and keeping my service available with persistent on,
I found if i turn persistent off, ignite handle very quickly, and cache usage less then 1G with same traffic, but when persistent flag enabled,
The OS cache memroy increasing vert quickly and exhaust all the available memroy, then ignite could not resume from this conditon and hang.

I have tried many parameters, use WALMODE, LOG_ONLY or BACKGROUND, set -DIGNITE_WAL_MMAP=false in JVM, set checkpointPageBufferSize, but none
of them could save my ignite service, it still eat the OS cache and exhaust it.

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/write-ahead-log
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/durable-memory-tuning#section-checkpointing-buffer-size

```
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <!-- 10 GB initial size. -->
                    <property name="initialSize" value="#{10L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <!-- 50 GB maximum size. -->
                    <property name="maxSize" value="#{50L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>

                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{1024L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
          <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
          <property name="walMode" value="LOG_ONLY"/>
          <property name="walPath" value="/wal/ebc"/>
          <property name="walArchivePath" value="/wal/ebc"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Bellow is my cache configuration:

```
public void createLvOneTxCache() {

    CacheConfiguration<String, OrderInfo> cacheCfg =
            new CacheConfiguration<>("LvOneTxCache");

    cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
    //cacheCfg.setStoreKeepBinary(true);
    cacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(ATOMIC);
    ebcLvOneTxCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
}
```

I have try to modify the parameters, but the OS cache still increasing:

```
    <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite native persistence. -->
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <!-- 10 GB initial size. -->
                    <property name="initialSize" value="#{4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <!-- 50 GB maximum size. -->
                    <property name="maxSize" value="#{4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>

                    <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
          <property name="checkpointFrequency" value="6000"/>
          <property name="checkpointThreads" value="32"/>
          <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
          <property name="walMode" value="LOG_ONLY"/>
          <property name="walPath" value="/wal/ebc"/>
          <property name="walArchivePath" value="/wal/ebc"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

And ignite log show audit quickly but the cache doesn't get released also.

```
[07:51:20,165][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#108][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint started [checkpointId=fd0c7e68-564a-4b40-9516-bb2a451869e7, startPtr=FileWALPointer [idx=23, fileOff=47849256, len=420491], checkpointLockWait=0ms, checkpointLockHoldTime=77ms, walCpRecordFsyncDuration=233ms, pages=7744, reason='timeout']
[07:51:20,219][INFO][sys-stripe-0-#1][PageMemoryImpl] Throttling is applied to page modifications [percentOfPartTime=0.36, markDirty=16378 pages/sec, checkpointWrite=3322 pages/sec, estIdealMarkDirty=673642 pages/sec, curDirty=0.00, maxDirty=0.40, avgParkTime=21501 ns, pages: (total=7744, evicted=0, written=7744, synced=229, cpBufUsed=0, cpBufTotal=1036430)]
[07:51:22,303][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#108][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint finished [cpId=fd0c7e68-564a-4b40-9516-bb2a451869e7, pages=7744, markPos=FileWALPointer [idx=23, fileOff=47849256, len=420491], walSegmentsCleared=0, markDuration=317ms, pagesWrite=24ms, fsync=2114ms, total=2456ms]
[07:51:26,117][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#108][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint started [checkpointId=d64991bc-3d2f-4f2c-8175-d7e92f46f0bf, startPtr=FileWALPointer [idx=25, fileOff=35951286, len=420491], checkpointLockWait=0ms, checkpointLockHoldTime=49ms, walCpRecordFsyncDuration=200ms, pages=7605, reason='timeout']
[07:51:28,612][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#108][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint finished [cpId=d64991bc-3d2f-4f2c-8175-d7e92f46f0bf, pages=7605, markPos=FileWALPointer [idx=25, fileOff=35951286, len=420491], walSegmentsCleared=0, markDuration=266ms, pagesWrite=23ms, fsync=2472ms, total=2761ms]
[07:51:32,118][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#108][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint started [checkpointId=07246861-57ae-4ef5-8419-cb7710d2f72d, startPtr=FileWALPointer [idx=27, fileOff=38042090, len=420491], checkpointLockWait=6ms, checkpointLockHoldTime=60ms, walCpRecordFsyncDuration=185ms, pages=7186, reason='timeout']
[07:51:32,121][INFO][service-#232][PageMemoryImpl] Throttling is applied to page modifications [percentOfPartTime=0.24, markDirty=10738 pages/sec, checkpointWrite=2757 pages/sec, estIdealMarkDirty=310976 pages/sec, curDirty=0.00, maxDirty=0.07, avgParkTime=358945 ns, pages: (total=7186, evicted=0, written=896, synced=0, cpBufUsed=565, cpBufTotal=1036430)]
[07:51:34,534][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#108][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint finished [cpId=07246861-57ae-4ef5-8419-cb7710d2f72d, pages=7186, markPos=FileWALPointer [idx=27, fileOff=38042090, len=420491], walSegmentsCleared=0, markDuration=257ms, pagesWrite=29ms, fsync=2387ms, total=2679ms]
[07:51:38,169][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#108][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint started [checkpointId=44e6870a-e370-4bd3-8ad9-8252abb0acd3, startPtr=FileWALPointer [idx=29, fileOff=44462293, len=420491], checkpointLockWait=0ms, checkpointLockHoldTime=76ms, walCpRecordFsyncDuration=210ms, pages=7529, reason='timeout']
[07:51:40,668][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#108][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint finished [cpId=44e6870a-e370-4bd3-8ad9-8252abb0acd3, pages=7529, markPos=FileWALPointer [idx=29, fileOff=44462293, len=420491], walSegmentsCleared=0, markDuration=303ms, pagesWrite=24ms, fsync=2475ms, total=2802ms]


[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        107G        995M        3.5G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        107G        995M        3.5G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        107G        995M        3.5G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        105G        995M        5.6G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
```

When I stop the traffic to update the cache, and i find the OS cache get back, but very very slow, it takes very long time to be released,
with quick checkpointFrequency 6s. How could this could be handled quickly?

```
[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        104G        995M        6.5G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        104G        995M        6.3G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        104G        995M        6.3G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        106G        995M        4.6G        109G
Swap:          127G          0B        127G
[root@Redis1 node00-296a5110-74ad-45e0-bf9c-5c075a4f5fdf]# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         14G        106G        995M        4.4G        109G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally fine that OS caches disk data, it's very good explained here [linux ate my ram](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/). If your kernel supports, you always may set amount of free memory, that could reduce pauses when Ignite allocates [new memory blocks](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.5/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning#section-page-cache)

Comment: Does the OS caches decrease means it has been used by ignite off-heap cache? as when persistent on, the route is: to be persistent data --> os cache ---> WAL log(same size with os cache, each 64M) --> persistent paritition file, and the checkpoint process periodicaly audit WAL log, move content to the partition file, and release the corresponding OS cache， when OS cache in low level , ignite service like hang with no reponse, so I think it's the checkpoint process could not audit the WAL log quickly enough and let OS cache recycled timely

Comment: as the description in you paste link, it seems it's ignite Page Cache cause this issue, not the ignite off-heap cache, right?

Comment: @dvlcis I am not sure there is a difference between a page cache and off-heap cache. In Ignite the pages are cached in off-heap memory.